# Extra modifications coming in commits

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github, git-extensions

I am working with Visual Studio 10 and using GIT as version control. I am using Git extensions as the plugin in VS to use GIT. I noticed a weird issue while doing commits, when I add a new line in a file say with text "a", the previous line is seen as removed and re-added in the commit. This is how it looks in commit window:

[image]

I didn't change the two lines highlighted in the screenshot. I added only the last line with text "a". **Can you let me know why the "another fix" line is showing as modified one**?
I am adding one more info here regarding the line ending settings, it is set as shown image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`core.autocrl` might be set to false, that doesn't mean the current eol (end of line) style used by your Visual Studio 10 editor isn't different from the eol used in that `README` file.

If the `README` has only [`\n` eol characters, and your line introduces a `\r\n` combination](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html), that would explain the change.

Reopening that file with Visual Studio should lead to this dialog box:

[image: normalization]

That would give you the opportunity to use only one style.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat related to what VonC said, the issue comes down to line endings. Though I don't think it was a change of a line ending, it was more likely the addition of one.

Specifically, the old version of your file ended with "`another fix`" and no newline at the end of the file. When you added the "`a`" on the next line, you effectively changed the "`another fix`" line to be "`another fix\n`" (or "`another fix\r\n`"), so git picks it up as a change.

In the future, you can make sure that your files end with a newline so when you add new lines like this, the git diff will only be the single line.